# An example/the example

Tags: articles

- I have found **an** example when people are given the option to choose their first car at the start of the game
- I have found **the** example when people are given the option to choose their first car at the start of the game.

Which article is better to use in this sentence?

Comment: As ever, it depends on whether it is a *particular* example. If you came across it during research, it would be "an example". If someone mentioned that they have seen an example, and you looked for it, then you found "the example".

Comment: Welcome! Since the two sentences say different things, can you tell us more about the context and which meaning you intend?

Comment: Olga, are these questions about "a" versus "the" ever going to stop? Just remember: a is for a general idea, the is for a specific one. There is no better one. They are different ideas.

Comment: I quite understand this, but sometimes this rule doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I like Alastair Montgomery's answer in the link provided by FumbleFingers. Your first sentence implies that there could be multiple such examples; your second sentence implies that there is only one such example.

If you have a pretty strict English teacher, then he or she might find fault with a couple of other things in your sentences. The following should be pretty unassailable: "I have found an/the example in which people are given the option to choose their first cars at the start of the game."